# Confused about basic algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So if you have the equation $(h^2+2h)/h=4$, you'd typically solve for h by dividing each term in the numerator by $h$, to get $h+2=4$, which gives $h=2$... simple algebra, right? Well, if you TIMES $h$ by $4$ then solve for $h$, you get two solutions for $h$, $0$ and $2$... I am confused, is the power rule that states $h^n/h^{n-1}= h$ incorrect??

Comment: If you allowed $h$ to be $0$, what have you done by multiplying both sides of the equation by $h$?

Answer (score 3):

You have got two solution $h=0,2$. However after getting the equation you must always check if the solution fit the equation. If you put $h=2$ in original equation you get $(2^2+2\cdot2)/2$ and you get $4$. However if you put $h=0$ then you get $(0^2+2\cdot0)/0$.
However division by $0$ is not possible thus the solution $h=0$ is eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

You get two candidate solutions.  The direction of the implication is that if the original equation holds, then the quadratic equation holds, **not vice-versa**.

As a simpler example, $x = 3 \implies x^2 = 9.$  The second equation has two candidate solutions of $x = \pm 3.$  Each candidate solution must be checked against the original equation $x = 3.$

Answer (score 1):

The first condition for the equation $\frac{(h^2+2h)}{h}=4$ is $h \ne 0$ because if $h = 0$ there is no mean to the equation. Thus, since $h \ne 0$, you can multiply both sides by $h$, which gives you:

$$h^2+2h =4h \ \Rightarrow h(h - 2) = 0$$

Since $h \ne 0$, only one solution for the equation, which is $h = 2$.

**Note:** I didn't see the connection between $\dfrac{h^n}{h^{n-1}}= h$ and the given equation. Still, the condition for the relation, $\dfrac{h^n}{h^{n-1}}= h$, is $h \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

See when you cancel $h$ from numerator and denominator, you automatically assume that $h\neq0$
because $\frac{a.b}{a.c}=\frac{b}{c}$ $and$ $a\neq0$. Hence you got a non zero solution for $h$ which also satisfies the condition $h\neq0$ .

When you bring $h$ on RHS. then also you automatically assume that $h\neq0$ but when you further solve you get two solutions $h=2$ and $h=0$, the latter which doesn't satisfies the condition $h\neq0$  and is hence rejected.